# Laravel Eloquent empty() function returns true for $request->url when there is a value

Tags: php, html, laravel, request, eloquent

I have a request that contains a url link that a user types in and submits(in Laravel).

```
SomeRequest ▼
  +request: ParameterBag ▼
    #parameters: array:4 ▼
      "title" => "cake"
      "url" => "www.someurl.com"
```

In my controller, when I call `empty($request->url)` it returns true even though it is not actually empty.  I have tried searching for an answer to this predicament to no avail.

Thanks.

Comment: try `!isset($var) || $var == false` instead. `empty()` is a PHP function and it most certainly works. Also your object has a key with `url1` but no key with `url` as far as I can see so `empty` should be `true`

Comment: Check your input and parameter you are trying to get.

Comment: I have used `dd(empty($request->url), $request->url);` and it has given me `true` and `"www.someurl.com"`

Comment: I have multiple title and url parameters, however, I mixed them into my question by accident as I only needed 1 to use to ask.  I have fixed them and removed the '1's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `$request->url` isn't a *normal* property. Internally the magic method `__get()` is called, which then returns the value from the parameter bag over a few other methods.

`empty()` doesn't know that and just checks (the same way as `isset()`) if the property exists. That's why you get `false` even though you can access `url`.

The best solution is probably to check with `has()`:

```
$request->has('url'); // returns true
```

---

Note that there's a way this could be "fixed" in the framework. That is by implementing the magic method `__isset()` which get's called when an `empty` or `isset` check is run.

Comment: That got it.  I figured it was something about it not being a normal string of sorts since its an object property and not a literal string.  Thanks.